# How to restart sliding animation in Easy Slider 1.7

Tags: jquery, slide, numeric, easyslider

I've got a question about the jQuery Easy Slider 1.7 http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider with numeric navigation.
When i use the slider with auto, continous set to true, the automatic sliding animation stops when I click on a number. Is there a way to make the animation after certain time delay?
I tried adding

```
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
             animate("next",false);
          },options.pause);
```

to

```
if(clicked) clearTimeout(timeout);
```

making it:

```
if(clicked) {clearTimeout(timeout);timeout = setTimeout(function()animate("next",false);},options.pause);}
```

But then after the sliding stops on click, when it restarts it simple continues in a single sliding motion(all images slide), then come on a blank display. After some time the images comes normally and the sliding starts again from image 1 and continues normally.