# Easy Slider 1.7 Restart

Tags: jquery, slider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restart sliding animation in Easy Slider 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978175/how-to-restart-sliding-animation-in-easy-slider-1-7)

I am looking for a work around that will restart easy slider 1.7. When a user clicks on the numeric controls the slider stops and will not restart again.

http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html

Answer (score 0):

Line 194 you can foud this code in easyslider1.7.js :

```
if(clicked) {clearTimeout(timeout);}
```

Replace what's inside the condition by what you're trying to achieve.